# Sharing Code Snippets in a Team?

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for a (if possible) web service/local server download of some kind that would allow me to share code snippets with my team at work. To increase the productivity of our team it seems like the best way to do this is for everyone in the team to submit code snippets with their name. So a way to share snippets on a local network (in the team) and a way to tell who submitted which code snippet when. I've looked a bit and I've found https://snipt.net which is fine but isn't really setup for a team from the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git for version control, and you are using version control right? :).  Github is the defacto standard in my opinion for sharing and managing code. They have free and paid plans that are very affordable.  The also to subversion hosting so you are covered on both fronts.

Comment: This is for automation actually and we use TestComplete for our automation. So all the scripts are stored on a server. I mean I wouldn't mind setting up a github just for a file for these code snippets though.